# Splitting of a String into a multiple element list in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a String "Student1Student2Student3" for example,  is there anyway i can turn this String into a list with three elements e.g. ["Student1", "Student2", "Student3"]?

The above string is just an example, "Student1" could be a random name of variable length. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I do your homework, would I get the grades as well?

Comment: Do you wan't to split when you see a string followed by a number?

Comment: What is the delimiter you want? An uppercase letter or is it always the same word? Everything's possible...

Comment: It could be any arbitrary name which could take the form "Joe Bloggs" for example.

Comment: Do you want split when you get big letter? Or number? Or something else?

Comment: The more detailed example you post the better answer you may get. For now answer is "split between number and upper-case character".

Comment: For the above example that would work, yes. I'm not sure how it would work if the string was "Joe BloggsJoe BloggJoe Blog" for eaxmple.

Comment: In the real code, "Student1" will be replaced by an arbitrary name. For example "Joe Blogs"

Comment: For your current example from comment potential answer could be "split between lower-case (from left) and upper-case character (from right)"

Comment: I think in the final code it would be ideal to split on a lowercase letter followed by an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33598915/splitting-of-a-string-into-a-multiple-element-list-in-java/33599026#comment54973369_33598915)

> I think in the final code it would be ideal to split on a lowercase letter followed by an uppercase letter.

it looks like you are looking for `split("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])")`.

[Look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms are zero-length which means they don't include in matched (in delimiter) characters they ware suppose to test. This will allow us to test lower-case character from left and upper-case from right but not consume it while splitting (since they will not be included in match).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)` to match specific parts of the string (for example in the string `Student1Student2Student3`, the first match would be `Student1`, and then `Student2`.

Here's a hint, use the Pattern class and the Matcher class

:) hopefully it will be enough to help you out.